# Activate headers after php request is complete

Tags: php, redirect, header, buffer

I am currently working on a site where users can upload images up to 10mb. When the users press upload, the file is stored in a directory on the server, and then the page is redirected through the use of a header. Note that I also put ob start() at the beginning of the script. The problem I'm having is that the header redirect activates before the request is complete, so users get logged out, or an internal server error occurs. Same thing happens when you delete the large file. I've tried removing the redirect and its fine, so i'm sure that's the problem. Is there a way to get the header redirect only after the php request (image upload) is complete?

Thanks!

Edit: Code sample

```
if (empty($errors)) {

  // Get the filename minus the file extension:
$filename = substr($image["name"], 0, strrpos($image["name"], "."));
// Append the appropriate extension
$filename .= $validMimes[$image['type']];
$location = "/home/shoplft/users/$user_id/$foldername/$filename";  
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);




  if($secondcategory=="0") {


     mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (users_user_id, name, brand, city, country, store, website, price, keywords, productlocation, filename) VALUES ('$user_id', '$productname', '$productbrand', '$city', '$country', '$store', '$website', '$price', '$tagwords', '$location', '$filename')") or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

     $pic_id = mysql_insert_id();

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, category) VALUES('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$firstcategory')");

     if(!empty($price)) {

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO svalues (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, svalue) VALUES ('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$price') ");

     }




  }



  else {

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (users_user_id, name, brand, city, country, store,   website, price, keywords, productlocation, filename) VALUES ('$user_id', '$productname', '$productbrand', '$city', '$country', '$store', '$website', '$price', '$tagwords', '$location', '$filename')") or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

  $pic_id = mysql_insert_id();

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, category) VALUES('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$firstcategory')");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, category) VALUES('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$secondcategory')");

  if(!empty($price)) {

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO svalues (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, svalue) VALUES ('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$price') ");

     }  


  }

header("Location: product.php?id=$pic_id");//prolly should separate data processing from output

 }
```

Comment: Code sample? Do you have the redirect code above the upload code? That's going to be an obvious reason.

Comment: @MichaelRushton, yeah I have it at the end. It's only on large files too, it's weird!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (empty($errors)) {

  // Get the filename minus the file extension:
$filename = substr($image["name"], 0, strrpos($image["name"], "."));
// Append the appropriate extension
$filename .= $validMimes[$image['type']];
$location = "/home/shoplft/users/$user_id/$foldername/$filename";
if(!@copy($tmp_name, $location))
{
$errors[] =  'Error';
}

if (empty($errors))
{




  if($secondcategory=="0") {


     mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (users_user_id, name, brand, city, country, store, website, price, keywords, productlocation, filename) VALUES ('$user_id', '$productname', '$productbrand', '$city', '$country', '$store', '$website', '$price', '$tagwords', '$location', '$filename')") or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

     $pic_id = mysql_insert_id();

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, category) VALUES('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$firstcategory')");

     if(!empty($price)) {

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO svalues (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, svalue) VALUES ('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$price') ");

     }




  }



  else {

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (users_user_id, name, brand, city, country, store,   website, price, keywords, productlocation, filename) VALUES ('$user_id', '$productname', '$productbrand', '$city', '$country', '$store', '$website', '$price', '$tagwords', '$location', '$filename')") or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

  $pic_id = mysql_insert_id();

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, category) VALUES('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$firstcategory')");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, category) VALUES('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$secondcategory')");

  if(!empty($price)) {

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO svalues (products_products_id, products_users_user_id, svalue) VALUES ('$pic_id', '$user_id', '$price') ");

     }


  }

header("Location: product.php?id=$pic_id");//prolly should separate data processing from output
 }
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code, and I'm getting the "file error upload" message

Comment: Try to remove "@" symbol in line --- if(!@move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location))?

Comment: If that aint gonna help, new codes will, check it out. That move_uploaded_file is for another purposes it seems. :P

Comment: Merrick, no dice? Just came from a coffee. Not to bother you, but seems there is some other problem with that stuff. Functions should work. Just to ask you are you working locally or on a host server?